# Java Color constructor casts long to float

Tags: java, casting

I was trying to draw gradients with Java (doesn't really matter what I was doing).

I have this line where it throws `IllegalStatementException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red`:

```
Color c = new Color(Math.round(col1r), Math.round(col1g), Math.round(col1b));
```

`col1r`, `col1g` and 'col1b' are all `double`s and are in range 0-255. `Math.round()` function returns `long`. While I expected it cast to `int` and use `Color(int r, int g, int b)` as constructor, it is cast to `float` and uses `Color(float r, float g, float b)` as constructor.

What is the reason for that?

P.S. I don't want a solution to get my program running, I can do that myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the specs say so: [JLS §5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Going from `long` to `int` is considered a *narrowing primitive conversion*. As in, it is considered that as a general principle (even if it doesn't apply in some specific case), long -> int is 'lossy'. Therefore, java will not do so unless you explicitly ask for it. Even in this trivial example where we don't have multiple overloads:

```
public void foo(int x) {}

long y = 5;
foo(y); // this will not compile
```

To ask for it, you either [A] cast: `foo((int) y);` would have worked, or [B] use an operation+assignment operator: `int x = 0; x += someLong;` actually works, this is a bit weird but, hey, the spec says so.

However, going from `long` to `double` or `float` is a so-called *Widening primitive conversion*: It is considered lossless (eventhough that is not technically true; if your long is larger than `2^52` or smaller than `-2^52` you may lose precision when converting a long to a double, for example) - and java will do that **silently**, there is no need to ask for it:

```
public void foo(double x) {}

long y = 5;
foo(y); // compiles just fine
```

Given the above, of all the various constructors that `Color` has, only `Color(double, double, double)` unambiguously and without needing to apply *narrowing primitive conversion* (which java won't do without you asking for it explicitly) fits given 3 longs for an argument.